# Hitting the database in loop

Tags: c#, performance

I am hitting the database in loop. Pls suggest how i can avoid this ?

```
 foreach (var assignedPricing in reviewingPricing)
      {
                    var assignedUserId = _wfActivitySvc.GetPricingReviewer(assignedPricing.PricingID).UserId;
                    if (assignedUserId == UserId)
                       {
                          reviewingAssignedPricings.Add(assignedPricing);
                       }
      }
```

Comment: send list to db and do bulk insert in one call

Comment: Can you give example code for above ?

Comment: What ORM do you use?

Comment: Back to the drawing board and define a new service contract to do this server side.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new query in your database service:

```
//Build an collection with just unique ids
var priceIds = reviewingPricing.Select(x => x.PricingId).Distinct();

//Return a key/value collection with all priceId/UserId
var reviewerMap = _wfActivitySvc.GetAllReviewersByPriceId(priceIds);

//now you can loop without db queries
foreach (var pricing in reviewingPricing)
{
    var reviewer = reviewMap.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PricingId == pricing.PricingId);
    if (reviewerMap == null)
        continue;
    if (reviewer.UserId == UserId)
    {
       reviewingAssignedPricings.Add(pricing);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You may want to insert all records at once. You can create stored procedure to do this. If you use SQL server you can use BulkInserter class: https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RonnieOverbyGrabBag/blob/master/BulkInserter.cs 
For production I had to tweak it a little bit internally to reduce its initialization time, but for infrequent bulk inserts Github version is just fine.
Usage example:

```
var bulkInserter = new BulkInserter<YourClass>(SqlConnection, "Table Name");
bulkInserter.Insert(reviewingAssignedPricings);
bulkInserter.Flush();
```

2) If this reads from database every time

```
_wfActivitySvc.GetPricingReviewer(assignedPricing.PricingID).UserId;
```

then replace it with single call outside loop to get all reviweres from database, then add to dictionary (key = priceID, value = reviewer) and then get reviewers from dictionary within loop. If you use simple List and .FirstOrDefault(), then it can be noticeably slow for 100+ items in list. jgauffin answer describes this idea.